# Update a line segment in python kivy after a fixed time

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a line and update is after a fixed interval of time (say 5 seconds). I wrote the code below but it does not update the line. Can anyone help me figure out who to do it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def my_callback(dt,ds):
        Line(points=[100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 200], width=10)
        pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = Line(points=[100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 200], width=1)
            self.line.width = 2
            Clock.schedule_once(self.my_callback, 5)
            pass
            # add your instruction for main canvas here

        with self.canvas.before:
            pass
            # you can use this to add instructions rendered before

        with self.canvas.after:
            pass
            # you can use this to add instructions rendered after

class LineExtendedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = GridLayout(cols=2, padding=50, spacing=50)
        root.add_widget(MyWidget())
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LineExtendedApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_callback` is not actually called within the `with` statement but rather 5s later when that is long gone, and even it if was it wouldn't do what you want - it would draw a new Line, not modify the existing one.

Instead you can change my_callback to do:

```
self.line.points = [100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 200]
self.line.width = 10
```

This will modify the existing line as you want. You can also take the clock scheduling out of the with statement but its position doesn't actually matter as long as it stays in the `__init__`